# Request $request no PHP orientado a objetos

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos

Eu estou fazendo alguns exercícios de PHP OO e me deparei com algumas funções que chamam uma classe antes da variavel. Mas nao entendi ao certo o pq disso.

Por exemplo:

```
public function Exemplo(Request $request, $nome, $sobrenome) {
   // métodos
}
```

se eu chamo uma deeteerminada classe para usar como parâmetro porque não se usa vírgula para se parar a classe da variável ?

Deve ser algo simples, mais isso está causando confusão aqui.
agradeço quem puder me esclarecer

abraço.

Comment: Não é parâmetro, aí está sendo avisado que $request é do "tipo" Request (nao pode por um inteiro, uma string ou outra coisa, tem que ser um objeto do tipo Request)

Comment: continuo confuso manu. Então a variavel $request será tratada como uma herença da classe Request ? herdando todos seus atributos e métodos ?

Comment: Isso significa se a variável que o laravel deve informar, deve ser um objeto do tipo Request. Ex: `$request = new Request(); $controller = new Controller(); $controller->Exemplo($request);`. Como o Bacco disse, não pode ser `$controller->Exemplo("string");` ou `$controller->Exemplo(123456)`.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#example-154

Comment: Hmm. Vamos supor que crio uma classe assim: `class Soma { public function Somar(){ return 25 + 25; } }` --- Dai eu quero chamar essa função em outra folha fazendo assim: `public function SomarTotal ( Somar $somar ) {}` dai na hra de chamar a funcao eu devo informar um objeto do tipo Somar, certo ? tipo isso: `$a = new SomarTotal; $a->Somar();` É isso ???? vish ta foda assimilar isso

Comment: Não é tão complexo. O nome disso é `Types Hinting`. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Opa, maravilha irmão. O nome já vale muito. Vou estudar a fundo aqui.. vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não há tipagem em php, a princípio... Mas nesse caso, a variável `$request` tem um tipo sim, o tipo `Request`.

Agora, imagine com a gente, você fazer um código, onde você atribui um `int` à variável `$request` por engano... Você iria perder todas as informações de $request: dados, cookies, tokens...

"Tipando" a variável `$request` você faz com que não sejam feitas atribuições desnecessárias nela, e perda acidental de variáveis.

PS.: Você não está usando uma classe como parâmetro, está definindo que `$request` é do tipo `Request`, assim como em linguagens tipadas você faz com outras variáveis, como `int numero;`, `double numero`, `String texto`...

Espero ter ajudado!